# How to execute a query with EntityFramework with relation many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a relation many to many in my database, I have a simple c# project and I use EntityFramework to connect at my database.
Now the tables are:

```
[dbo].[PE_Attivita](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Descrizione] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [IDAttivitaPare] [int] NULL,
    [CodiceCategoria] [int] NULL,
    [NomeAttivita] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [NomeFileEseguibile] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [isVisible] [bit] NULL
)
[dbo].[ANAG_OperatoriMedici](
    [CodicePersoneFisiche] [nvarchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Descrizione] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
[dbo].[PE_AttivitaXMedico](
    [CodiceFiscaleOperatoreMedico] [nvarchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [IDAttivita] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Now I want to execute a query to extract the all data from PE_AttivitaXMedico.

If I try to search the PE_AttivitaXMedico class in my workspace I can't search it. I try to write this code but not works:

```
activityForDoctors= from ad in db_data.PE_Attivita
    select new ActivityDTO.activitysXDoctors
    {
        IdAttivita=ad.ID,
        codiceFiscaleDottore=ad.ANAG_OperatoreMedico.
    }
```

because in PE_Attivita the ANAG_OperatoreMedico is a collection and not an object, how can I fixed it?

EDIT

This is my PE_Attivita model

```
public partial class PE_Attivita
    {
        public PE_Attivita()
        {
            this.MONITOR_Dati_Attivita_Esecuzione = new HashSet<MONITOR_Dati_Attivita_Esecuzione>();
            this.PE_Schedulazione_Attivita = new HashSet<PE_Schedulazione_Attivita>();
            this.PE_Attivita1 = new HashSet<PE_Attivita>();
            this.PE_AttivitaXIndici = new HashSet<PE_AttivitaXIndici>();
            this.PE_AttivitaXParametri = new HashSet<PE_AttivitaXParametri>();
            this.ANAG_OperatoriMedici = new HashSet<ANAG_OperatoriMedici>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Descrizione { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IDAttivitaPare { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CodiceCategoria { get; set; }
        public int CreationUserID { get; set; }
        public int LastChangeUserID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
        public int FileStateID { get; set; }
        public string NomeAttivita { get; set; }
        public string NomeFileEseguibile { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isVisible { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MONITOR_Dati_Attivita_Esecuzione> MONITOR_Dati_Attivita_Esecuzione { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PE_Schedulazione_Attivita> PE_Schedulazione_Attivita { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PE_Attivita> PE_Attivita1 { get; set; }
        public virtual PE_Attivita PE_Attivita2 { get; set; }
        public virtual PE_CategoriaAttivita PE_CategoriaAttivita { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PE_AttivitaXIndici> PE_AttivitaXIndici { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PE_AttivitaXParametri> PE_AttivitaXParametri { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ANAG_OperatoriMedici> ANAG_OperatoriMedici { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the ANAG_OperatoriMedici model

```
public partial class ANAG_OperatoriMedici
    {
        public ANAG_OperatoriMedici()
        {
            this.ANAG_OperatoriMediciXAssistiti = new HashSet<ANAG_OperatoriMediciXAssistiti>();
            this.PE_Schedulazione_Attivita = new HashSet<PE_Schedulazione_Attivita>();
            this.ANAG_Associazioni = new HashSet<ANAG_Associazioni>();
            this.PE_Attivita = new HashSet<PE_Attivita>();
        }

        public string CodicePersoneFisiche { get; set; }
        public string Descrizione { get; set; }

        public virtual ANAG_PersoneFisiche ANAG_PersoneFisiche { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ANAG_OperatoriMediciXAssistiti> ANAG_OperatoriMediciXAssistiti { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PE_Schedulazione_Attivita> PE_Schedulazione_Attivita { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ANAG_Associazioni> ANAG_Associazioni { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PE_Attivita> PE_Attivita { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to interpret your question without classes, but if you just want 1 from the collection, use

```
codiceFiscaleDottore=ad.ANAG_OperatoreMedico.FirstOrDefault().CodiceFiscaleOperatoreMedico
```

If you want all combinations, SelectMany() comes in handy:

```
activityForDoctors = from ad in db_data.PE_Attivita
.SelectMany(c => c.ANAG_OperatoreMedico)
select ad
```

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/

Comment: I have use your code, but I received the duplicate data. I want all combinations IDAttivita, CodiceFiscale

Comment: Post your models, not the database.